# jQuery .hide() button when another button active

Tags: html, jquery

I have a "Load More" button that has a class named `.btn.btn-primary.ng-scope`. When we have some items to show and class `.btn.btn-primary.ng-scope.ng-hide` when all units loaded.

My problem is that I have another button "Show All Available Units" with class `.btn.btn-primary.custom`. I need to show button "Show ALL Units" ONLY when button "Load More" has class `.ng-hide`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (jQuery('.btn.btn-primary.ng-hide')) {
    jQuery('.btn.btn-primary.custom').show();
  }
  
  if (jQuery('.btn.btn-primary.ng-show')) {
    jQuery('.btn.btn-primary.custom').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to add the code to show the 'All units' button in to the logic which add the `.ng-hide` class to the 'Load more' button. I presume this is an AJAX callback? It would be possible to do what you need using something like a mutation observer, but it's a crude workaround.

Comment: Is there a way to check if .ng-hide exists ? I need show button "Show ALL units" only why we no more see button "Load More" (means only when button 'load More' has class .ng-hide)

Comment: Assuming the class is added when the page loads: `if($('.btn.btn-primary.ng-scope').hasClass('.ng-hide')) { ... }`